# How do I display these values above their respective bars on this bar chart with matplotlib? My attempts are not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I need to display the values above their respective bars. Can't quite figure it out. I have been trying for loops, and was told to possibly use patches but I'm pretty new at this still and having some trouble. Help would be appreciated! The pictures include the short bit of code from the jupyter notebook.

Here is the pseudocode

```
df=read_csv
df.sort_values
df = df/2233*100.round

ax=df.plot(bar)
ax.set_title
ax.tick_params
ax.legend

for i, value in enumerate(df):
    label=str(value)
    ax.annotate(label, xy=(i, value))
```

[First step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtk3H.png)

[Second step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fCPb.png)

The actual code I try,

```
for i, value in enumerate(df_dstopics):
    label = str(value)
    ax.annotate(label, xy=(i, value))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python - how to show values on top of bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53066633/python-how-to-show-values-on-top-of-bar-plot)

Answer (score 2):

Parameter *xy* in [ax.annotate()](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html) needs to be a tuple which represents a point in coordinate system. However, the `value` in your `for i, value in enumerate(df)` is column name, which is definitely not a valid constant.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Very interested':np.random.rand(2), 'Somewhat interested':np.random.rand(2)+1, 'Not interested':np.random.rand(2)+2})

ax = df.plot(kind='bar', color=['r','b','g']) 

for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(s=np.round(p.get_height(), decimals=2),
                xy=(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2., p.get_height()),
                ha='center',
                va='center',
                xytext=(0, 10),
                textcoords='offset points')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Reference:

- [Annotate bars with values on Pandas bar plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447700/annotate-bars-with-values-on-pandas-bar-plots)
- [Python pandas / matplotlib annotating labels above bar chart columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23591254/python-pandas-matplotlib-annotating-labels-above-bar-chart-columns)